# How to cast from Error to CFError in Swift?

Tags: swift

Having error of type `Error`, I'm finding it particularly tricky to cast it to `CFError` without having Xcode either issuing a warning or a compilation error. Has anyone come across this issue?

(using Xcode 11.0 and Swift 5)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why not just skip `guard`?

Comment: What is the type of `error`? I can't reproduce the warning you get in Xcode 11.1 Swift 5.1 with `error` declared as `Error`.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I do. If you're in a `catch` block there seems to be no way to cast the error to a CFError except by using `let cfError = error as! CFError` with no guard

Comment: The cast never fails so you just need `cfError: CFError = error as CFError`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation on https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cferror-ru8, `CFError is toll-free bridged to NSError in the Foundation framework`. By casting Error to NSError instead of CFError, we solve Xcode's warning and error. Also we can do:

```
let nserror = cfError as Error as NSError
```